# Function approximation with Maclaurin series

Tags: c, approximation, taylor-series

I need to approx (1-x)^0.25 with given accuracy (0.0001 e.g.). I'm using [expansion found on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#List_of_Maclaurin_series_of_some_common_functions) for (1+x)^0.25. I need to stop approximating when current expression is less than the accuracy.

```
long double s(long double x, long double d) {
    long double w = 1;
    long double n = 1; // nth expression in series
    long double tmp = 1;

    // sum while last expression is greater than accuracy
    while (fabsl(tmp) >= d) {
        tmp *= (1.25 / n - 1) * (-x); // the next expression
        w += tmp; // is added to approximation
        n++; 
    } 

    return w;
}
```

Don't mind long double n. :P This works well when I'm not checking value of current expression but when I'm computing 1000 or more expressions. Domain of the function is <-1;1> and s() calculates approximation well for x in <-1;~0.6>. The bigger the argument is the bigger is the error of calculation. From 0.6 it exceeds the accuracy.

I'm not sure if the problem is clear enough because I don't know English math language well. The thing is what's the matter with while condition and why the function s() doesn't approximate correctly.

**EDIT:**
Problem mostly solved. When x>0 I have to substract absolute value of consecutive expressions from 1.

```
if (x<0)
   w += tmp;
else
   w -= fabsl(tmp);
```

After that accuracy increases a lot (fox x>0 of course). Redundant error stems from long double inaccuracy. That's all. Thanks anyway to you guys.

Comment: If you want uniform accuracy on an interval you should be using a polynomial determined using Remez's algorithm, not Taylor. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory

Comment: @Pascal This would best be implemented as `sqrt(sqrt(1.0-x))` but this is a homework exercise. The point is not the efficiency of the algorithm, but the ability of the student to implement the algorithm.

Comment: Do you have your compiler warnings turned on? Do you have a C99 compiler (where `fabsl` is described) or a C89 compiler (with no `fabsl`)?

Comment: @pmg, I'm using GCC 4.5, compiling both in c89 and c99 mode. Nothing changes.

Comment: @Pascal: Chebyshev polynomials are easier to compute.

Comment: @marines please remember to accept one of the answers

Comment: @David what if none helped me?

Comment: @marines You don't have to accept an answer if you don't feel any of them helped. However, if we didn't help it's entirely down to you. Perhaps you don't realise it but your update with the different code for (x>0) is in fact identical to your original code! When x>0, try printing out +tmp and -fabs(tmp) at each iteration and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Try drawing graph of function

```
abs((1.0+x)alpha - binomial_formula(alpha,x,tolerance))
```

even in close x range such as [-0.5;0.5] you will get something like:
[image]

This means that your binomial expansion implementation is unstable. As x gets further and further from zero - series must include more and more terms for given accuracy. But doing so in current expansion implementation causes [Catastrophic cancellation](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/91float/) to occur (some floating point error accumulation mechanism). Try reading my given link on how to design numerically stable algorithm.

BTW, thanks for really interesting problem !

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that whilst the iteration part of your algorithm is fine, the termination is not what you think it is.

The Taylor series expansion you are using is exact when the infinite sum is evaluated. However, you cannot evaluate that infinite sum and are truncating.

I suppose you are assuming that when `tmp` becomes smaller than your desired tolerance, then the error in `w` is also less than that tolerance.

However, this is not true. The error, at each iteration is the infinite sum of the remaining terms. It is the sum of the infinite number of terms that you are throwing away.  The first one of these, the value of `tmp` at the point of termination, may be less that your tolerance, but the sum of them all may be greater than your tolerance.

You happen to get away with it when (-x) is negative because the alternating sign of `tmp` works in your favour. And when (-x) is positive you get away with it when `x` is close to zero.

However, I'm not convinced there is an easy way to come up with a simple general purpose stopping criteria. You'd have to be able to put some bounds on the terms which you are throwing away.  This now becomes a mathematical problem rather than a programming problem.

Comment: +1. As an heuristic the magnitude of the first neglected term usually gives a rough indication of the truncation error. But here, there is another (numerical) problem with the fact that the sum is alternating.

Comment: @Alexandre It's only alternating when `(-x)` is negative and this is the case where the erroneous stopping criteria performs better. It when `tmp` does not have alternating sign that the truncation error is more troublesome, but possibly easier to calculate mathematical bounds.

Comment: true, but the problem of summing an alternative series is *numerically* difficult.

Comment: @Alexandre True, but at the tolerance levels required here, and for this problem, I don't think you hit those issues. All in all it seems an odd assignment. I think I'd have chosen something with a more tractable termination criterion!